# How to choose which WIX dialog to show OnExit based on condition

Tags: dialog, wix, conditional-statements, show, ca

I have two WIX dialogs in my setup project

Final form which is to be shown when installer terminates with status 'success'

```
<Dialog Id="FinishedForm">
   ...
</Dialog>
```

and page to show several slides about our Product.

```
<Dialog Id="IntroductionTourPage">
   ...
   <Control Id="SkipTourButton" Type="PushButton">
      <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="FinishedForm">1</Publish>
   </Control>
   ...
</Dialog>
```

I want IntroductionTourPage is only to be shown after product is installed(not upgraded or removed), but I do not know how to do that. I tried

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="FinishedForm" OnExit="success">Condition</Show>
    <Show Dialog="IntroductionTourPage" OnExit="success">NOT Condition</Show>
</InstallUISequence>
```

but it is not valid in Wix so it this approach failed. Then I tried

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="FinishedForm" Sequence="1">Condition</Show>
    <Show Dialog="IntroductionTourPage" Sequence="2">NOT Condition</Show>
</InstallUISequence>
```

it didn't work. I tried then

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="FinishedForm" OnExit="success"/>
    <Show Dialog="IntroductionTourPage" Before="FinishedForm">Condition</Show>
</InstallUISequence>
```

but it is not valid in Wix as well.

Now I want to try smth like:

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <Custom Action="CA_ChooseAndShowDialogBasedOnCondition" OnExit="success"/>
</InstallUISequence>
```

but I can't find any example how to show Wix dialogs from CA.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Andriy

Comment: I'm also thinking about implementing CA which dinamically creates UI(example: http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/07/dynamic-windows-installer-ui.html) but I can't find any detailed tutorial regarding this technique

Comment: @Vinoth, your approach is viable, but I have a lot of controls in each dialog, and some of these controls already use conditions <Condition Action="show/hide">, I do not want the code to become total mess.

Answer (score 1):

I have something different solution for you. Try this if you found this is suitable for your requirement.

Add all controls in your **FinishedForm** to **IntroductionTourPage**.  Use **IntroductionTourPage** as the Success exit dialog. Display the controls in **IntroductionTourPage** dialog based on the condition.

Now **IntroductionTourPage** will act as both `FinishedForm` and `IntroductionTourPage` as per the condition. You can use FinishedForm dialog from IntroductionTourPage if required.

**Example:** Title Control in IntroductionTourPage

```
   <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="188" Y="22" Width="330" Height="22" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Welcome to the IntroductionTourPage" >
            <Condition Action="hide">Condition</Condition>
   </Control>
  <Control Id="FinishTitle" Type="Text" X="188" Y="15" Width="316" Height="22" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Completed the Sample Setup Wizard" Hidden="yes">
            <Condition Action="show">Condition</Condition>
  </Control>
```